# Any reason not to have blank lines of code in Bash script (historical or otherwise)

Tags: bash

Google-foo is failing me.  My question regards the actual Bash shell script itself.  Is there a current or historical reason one would not want any blank lines in a shell script?  Consider two versions of the following somewhat silly code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the time
TIME=$(date "+%H")
GREET=""

# Find the proper greeting
if [ $TIME -lt 12 ]; then
    # Less than 12 means it's morning
    GREET="Good morning"
    
elif [ $TIME -lt 18 ]]; then
    # Less than 18 means it's afternoon
    GREET="Good afternoon"
    
else
    # Must be evening
    GREET="Good evening"
fi

# Greet the user
echo "${GREET}"
```

Contrast that with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Get the time
TIME=$(date "+%H")
GREET=""
#
# Find the proper greeting
if [ $TIME -lt 12 ]; then
    # Less than 12 means it's morning
    GREET="Good morning"
#    
elif [ $TIME -lt 18 ]]; then
    # Less than 18 means it's afternoon
    GREET="Good afternoon"
#    
else
    # Must be evening
    GREET="Good evening"
fi
#
# Greet the user
echo "${GREET}"
```

Notice how there are **no** blank lines at all in the second version?  I've encountered code written by others (that have since moved on) that look like the second version.  I'm wondering if there is any current or historical reason to do that?

Any time I try to search for "comment every line" or something similar, I get posts that talk about how to clear blank lines from other text files - not why one would want this in their bash script.

So again, is this a matter of personal taste?  Or is there some reason, current or historical, where one would make sure there are no empty code lines at all?

Comment: There is no historical reason to do so; people who write that code may simply have a poor understanding of how the shell processes its input.

Comment: It doesn't matter at all. There can be any number of new lines between the different keywords of an if statement.

Comment: It's a stylistic thing. Some folks like spaces to break up the code and make it readable, others maybe like to maximise the amount of code they can see on the terminal window. There used to be a need to preserve disk space so people used tabs instead of spaces and reduced white space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this a matter of personal taste?

Yes.

> is there some reason, current or historical, where one would make sure there are no empty code lines at all?

No.

The only reason I can think of, that sometimes I use, is that `{` `}` [motions](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%7B) in VIM editor jump up to the first non-empty lines. So if you want to have visual separation, but want `{` `}` paragraph motions to skip over a whole block of file, you just put `#` comment so that the line is not empty and is counted as part of paragraph. But, that makes sense to have lines with just `#` in parts of the file, not the entire file.

Comment: The code above is an example - the real code is roughly 200 lines with no breaks at all.  So I'm agreeing, it's probably not VIM motions.  Thanks!